# Why Persistent class is not working for ZODB

Tags: python, persistent, zodb

Im new to the ZODB and Python in general. Im following tutorial from this page:
http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/articles/ZODB1.html

On that page under "Persistent Classes" section there is a piece of code:

```
import ZODB
from Persistence import Persistent
```

For some reason it gives me error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Persistence'"

What am i missing ? Creating and connecting to database works just fine.

Comment: The tutorial might be out of date. IIRC, the module is now named `persistent`, i.e., use `from persistent import Persistent`; see [here](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/guide/writing-persistent-objects.html#adding-attributes) for example

Comment: Thank you for the help. I figured it out.

Comment: That tutorial is for ZODB1; look at http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/tutorial.html instead, the module is now called `persistence` (lowercased).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article is fairly old now and assumes ZODB version 1.x; look at http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/tutorial.html instead, the module is now called `persistence` (lowercased):

```
from persistence import Persistence
```

For more in-depth information, there is also the [*Writing persistent objects* section](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/guide/writing-persistent-objects.html) of the ZODB programming guide.

Comment: Thank you for the help.